# Get SmallWorld 2 running on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: games, steam

On Ubuntu 20.04 Small World, installed via Steam, is not starting. I found [these instructions](https://7thzero.com/blog/get-smallworld-2-running-on-ubuntu-16-04), but it all seems a bit different on my system.

How do I get Small World running?

---

UPDATE:
I managed to get the game running (see my answer below) but the multiplayer part dowsn't work: I cannot find any of the other players online. If I start Small World 2 from the console, I see, that it successfully queries an online URL for the player info I search for but then sais "user not found" nonetheless.

How can I get the online game running?

Answer (score 0):

My install folder is

```
GAME=/media/Win10/SteamLibrary-Linux/steamapps/common/SmallWorld2
```

And the library path for the game in the steam folder is

```
STEAM=~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SmallWorld2/lib/
```

I started the game from the console with

```
cd $GAME
./Small\ World\ 2
```

Then you see the missing libraries one at a time. You have to locate all missing libraries and link them into the Steam library path:

```
cd $STEAM
LOCAL_LIBS=~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s $LOCAL_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0
STEAM_RUNTIME_LIBS=~/.steam-dist/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386
sudo ln -s $STEAM_RUNTIME_LIBS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s $STEAM_RUNTIME_LIBS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
sudo ln -s $STEAM_RUNTIME_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10
sudo ln -s $STEAM_RUNTIME_LIBS/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0

cd $GAME
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.6.0.21 libstdc++.so.6
```